# how to force OCaml to infer a more general type?

Tags: ocaml

I want to define a function that accepts an optional argument which is a function ('a -> 'b). The default value should be the identity, which is actually `('a -> 'a)`, but i see no reason why it should not be compatible with the more general `('a -> 'b)`. When i try:

```
let optional_apply ?f i =
    match f with 
    | None -> i + 4
    | Some fn -> fn (i + 4)
```

I always get the narrow type `?f:(int -> int) -> int -> int`. But I want to keep f as `int -> 'b`. What can i do? Or is this just unsound, since `optional_apply` would not have a definite type? If so, how would I get a similar functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible, the `f` argument must not be optional.  A simple explanation, is that optional parameters are just a syntactic sugar. 
So without sugar your function can be rewritten in a following form:

```
let optional_apply f n = match f with
  | Some f -> f (n + 4)
  | None -> (n + 4)
```

And here typechecker allows us only one type for `f`: `int -> int`. If it allowed us an `int -> 'a` type, then the `None` path of expression would be unsound. In other words, depending on whether `f` is `None` or `Some` the `optional_apply` will evaluate to different types. And this is considered unsound.

The best way to prove the unsoundness is to give a simple example where typechecker will allow unsound program:

```
let f = ref None
let g n = optional_apply ?f:!f n
```

with this definitions, if type checker allowed `f` parameter to remain polymorphic, then we can at any time "break" `g` function by changing `f` reference to anything else.

Comment: Ok, so the way to think about optional arguments is as `option` types that are fixed at the time of the definition of the function. I wrongly imagined something like a lazy typing construct with does not get looked at until needed. But this is probably nonsense in the context of Ocaml.

Answer (score 2):

**This is not compatible with the general type `('a -> 'b)`.** Here's why:

- The first pattern, `None -> i + 4` is of type `int`, thus restricting the function's return type to `int`.
- The second pattern, `Some fn -> fn (i + 4)` must then *also* be of type `int`. Because `(i + 4)` is of type `int`, too, `fn` must take and return an `int`, thus `int -> int`.

---

The best alternative I can think of is Haskell's `maybe` function, of type `('a -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a option -> 'b`:

```
let maybe fn backup opt = match opt with
    | Some v -> fn v
    | None   -> backup
;;
```

... which you can probably adapt to your use case.

Comment: I agree with your explanation. It's just difficult to understand why it has to be that way. With a non-optional argument `f` instead of `?f`, the function is just a plain `apply` and there is no problem keeping the type of `f` general. `apply` is polymorphic and can be re-used with `f` of different types, no problem.